# What Could be the MySQL query to fetch the 3rd Maximum Value from a column in DB-table?

Tags: mysql

I was asked once,

What Could be the MySQL query to fetch the 3rd Maximum Value from a column in DB-table?

Please help me to have multiple way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**first way:**

for **nth** highest column

```
   SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT n-1, 1
```

**Second way :** ( eg : for **N'th highest  salary** ) not tested

```
SELECT id FROM EMPLOYEE E1 WHERE 
 (N - 1) = (SELECT COUNT(distinct(SAL)) 
            FROM EMPLOYEE E2 
            WHERE E2.SAL > E1.SAL )
```

**BASIC  lOGIC:**

> You could sort the column into *descending* format and then just obtain
>   the value from the nth row.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail how it works? Above second query will work for Nth number of record but I am not getting the exact meaning... TIA.

Comment: First run sub query and see what it returns.

Comment: Its returning me number of counts that I am having. In my case its returning me 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
Row_Number
```

is the function will help you to get any record from your table.

```
WITH Sample AS
(
    SELECT id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY idno) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM TableName
) 

SELECT * 
FROM Sample 
WHERE RowNumber = 3;
```

Comment: @Martin - SQL Tag is there as well. So My question should not be downvoted

Comment: That is not the normal interpretation of the tag system on SO. If it has a specific RDBMS tag then an answer that can be used for that RDBMS is generally expected. Additionally the question text itself asks for **What Could be the MySQL query** which should remove any doubts.

Comment: SQL is a generic tag (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) and does not mean MS SQL. The question is asking about a solution for MySQL hence the MySQL tag.

Comment: Understood. I will take care of it. Should I delete my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT columns FROM table ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 2,1
```